# forecast::thetaf error

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I currently have problems with the forecast package 8.2 and the thetaf function:

```
dat<- structure(c(5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 2, 0, 1, 
0, 2.1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2, 2, 0, 1.7, 0, 1.5, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0), .Tsp = c(1999, 2003.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")
library(forecast)
thetaf(dat,h = 1)$mean
```

gives the following error

```
Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, allow.multiplicative.trend =  allow.multiplicative.trend,  : 
  y should be a univariate time series
Additional: Warnings:
1: In ets(x, "ANN", alpha = alpha, opt.crit = "mse", lambda = lambda,  :
  Missing values encountered. Using longest contiguous portion of time series
2: In fit$call <- match.call() : ...
```

The error has to do with the frequency. If it is 1 instead of 12 then it works. I do not see a reason why this should cause an error. Any ideas?

Comment: If the zeros are the problem, why would the the function then work if I reduce the frequency to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applied to seasonal data, the theta method uses a multiplicative classical decomposition to remove the seasonality. In this case, the decomposition fails:

```
> decompose(dat, type="multiplicative")
$x
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1999 5.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2000 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2001 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.9 0.0 2.0 0.0
2002 1.0 0.0 2.1 0.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 2.0
2003 2.0 0.0 1.7 0.0 1.5 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 0.0

$seasonal
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug
1999 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
2000 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
2001 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
2002 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
2003 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
           Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1999 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410
2000 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410
2001 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410
2002 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410
2003 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410

$trend
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug
1999        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.9583333 0.9166667
2000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.0000000
2001 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0375000 0.0750000 0.1583333 0.2416667 0.2833333 0.3250000
2002 0.7083333 0.7500000 0.7125000 0.6750000 0.6958333 0.8000000 0.9250000 0.9666667
2003 0.8916667 0.8916667 0.8916667 0.8916667 0.8916667 0.8083333        NA        NA
           Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1999 0.7083333 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.4166667
2000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2001 0.4125000 0.5000000 0.5833333 0.6666667
2002 0.9500000 0.9333333 0.9125000 0.8916667
2003        NA        NA        NA        NA

$random
           Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug
1999        NA       NaN        NA       NaN        NA        NA 0.0000000       NaN
2000 2.1793043       NaN 0.0000000       NaN 0.0000000       NaN 0.0000000       NaN
2001       NaN       NaN 0.0000000       NaN 0.0000000       NaN 0.0000000       NaN
2002 0.2563887       NaN 2.3017827       NaN 2.3911982       NaN 3.7907196       NaN
2003 0.4073466       NaN 1.4889369       NaN 1.3995214       NaN        NA       NaN
           Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
1999 0.0000000       NaN 0.0000000 0.0000000
2000       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2001 2.8430397       NaN 1.5802682 0.0000000
2002 0.0000000       NaN 1.2627714 2.8430397
2003        NA       NaN        NA        NA

$figure
 [1] 5.5063443 0.0000000 1.2804721 0.0000000 1.2020131 0.0000000 0.2851915 0.0000000
 [9] 0.7674245 0.0000000 2.1696136 0.7889410

$type
[1] "multiplicative"

attr(,"class")
[1] "decomposed.ts"
```

The problem arises because April, June, August and October have zero seasonal indices, so dividing by the seasonal index creates `NaN` values.

I have fixed the problem (in v8.3 of the forecast package) to proceed with a non-seasonal version of the theta method when this happens.